# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        scrollTo: function (target, callback) {
            var offset = $(target).offset().top - this.config.navHeight;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: offset
            }, this.config.scrollSpeed, this.config.easing, callback);
        },

        unbindInterval: function () {
            clearInterval(this.t);
            this.$win.unbind('scroll.onePageNav');
        }
    };

    OnePageNav.defaults = OnePageNav.prototype.defaults;

    $.fn.onePageNav = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            new OnePageNav(this, options).init();
        });
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

I get this error when I'm scrolling down each time Developer Console runs.
(In my [website](https://jimmydance.com/) all js are minified and combined to one file.)

Comment: how is `scrollTo` called?

Comment: `offset()` will return `undefined` if the jQuery object contains no elements (ie, `target` cannot be found)

Comment: also there is a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` error in your page

Comment: I don't have enough experience in this field as I'm still learning.
The issue is appears (in Dev Console) every time you click on "CLASSES" or "SHOWS".
@Arun: Can't see the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" in my system.

Comment: Your file https://jimmydance.com/js/jjs.js has `<!--MODERNIZR-->` syntax for comments which is valid in html/xml but not in a script file instead use `/*MODERNIZR*/`

Comment: @Arun: I did use the "//" (without quotation) to comment but as I remember something was going wrong. But still, why is invisible to me (the syntax error)?
And of course, is something I can do to solve the main issue?

Comment: @Jim unless this issue is fixed we are not able to recreate the problem... without which we may not be able to solve it... so change the comments....  you may have to clear your browser cache to see the problem

Comment: @Arun: I cleared my browser cache and nothing comes up...

Comment: @Jim then I'm afraid there is nothing much I can do.... If I open the page https://jimmydance.com/js/jjs.js it shows me minified script with `<!-- -->` used for comment

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes, there is a comment like <!-- -->. But in my system is not visible (is visible only in the editor) and there is no syntax error indication.
What should I do in order to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yep, you were right! I so that just now! So sorry for this!
Now, that the syntax error is fixed, is there any way to fix the main issue?

Comment: Now if you look at the console you can see an error like `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`... that is because you have `$(document).ready(function(){$(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();});` before `<script async src="js/jxxjs.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is The `Classes` and `Shows` elements do not have a `href` target, its value is just `#`, so jQuery is not able to find any result for `$('#')` that is why `t(i).offset()` is returning undefined.

The solution could be is to check whether the target element exists in the `scrollTo` method like

```
scrollTo: function (target, callback) {
    var $target = $(target);
    if (!$target.length) {
        return;
    }
    var offset = $target.offset().top - this.config.navHeight;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: offset
    }, this.config.scrollSpeed, this.config.easing, callback);
}
```